# Como crear un directorio global en C#?

Tags: c#, imagen, rutas, picturebox

estoy llamando una imagen de una carpeta en mi proyecto a una PictureBox:

```
if (comboNorma.Text == "English units") {
                        if (txtCurva.Text == "CS_6") {
                            picCurva.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\DSEM\\ASME_II\\ASME_II\\assets\\curvas\\CS_6.png");
                        }
if (txtCurva.Text == "CS_1") {
                                picCurva.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\DSEM\\ASME_II\\ASME_II\\assets\\curvas\\CS_1.png");
                        }
                    }
```

Funciona, pero intento que en lugar de introducir toda la dirección de mi carpeta contenedora de imágenes en cada sección lo haga una sola vez y que finalmente solo introduzca el nombre de la imagen por cada sección, algo así:

```
curvas/CS_1.png
```

De forma que curvas contiene la dirección que contiene las imágenes.

Soy nuevo en C#.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. Podrías usar rutas relativas (al directorio de trabajo). Puedes cambiar el directorio de trabajo con [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory). Para facilitar la búsqueda de archivos también puedes usar un [`OpenFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementando lo de Mateo, puedes hacer algo así:

```
var ruta = @"C:\Users\DELL\Documents\DSEM\ASME_II\ASME_II\asset\";
if (comboNorma.Text == "English units") {
   picCurva.Image = Image.FromFile(@$"{ruta}{txtCurva.Text}.png");
}
```

en donde se crea una variable con la ruta base y dentro del if asignamos el valor de manera dinamica con el $, es importante considerar el CaseSensitive de las imagenes.

Solo tendrías que revisar la ruta que sea dinámica, podriás hacer algo como:

```
var ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: cuantos años de experiencia tienes???